# Convert Python scripts to executable file without getting any dll errors on windows 7?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Is there  any way we can convert Python scripts to executable file without getting any dll errors? I tried with pyinstaller but it does not runs easily, I am getting many different dll errors like api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll not found in different Windows systems. I even tried installing vc redistribute which seems to work on some systems but that is also not getting installed in many systems. Please help.[image]

[image]

Comment: How in the world can anyone help you with this? You haven't specified the errors that you're receiving or the dlls that you're referencing

Comment: What options did you use to build the `exe` and how did you run it. What errors are being shown. Please post enough information for the question!

Comment: I have mentioned that I used pyinstaller!

Comment: First, make sure that the architecture of your Python is the same as the MSVC you are trying to install. (E.g if you are using a 64-bit Python you need to install X64 of MSVC). Also, try to remove the cached pyinstaller files from `C:/<User>/AppData/Roaming/PyInstaller`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download the api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0 file dll file `[link][1]`

Update your universal C Runtime and install windows 7 version here [C runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)

download Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 and 2015
[2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and [2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

work?